# VisualSVN Server + Trac Authentication Problems

Tags: svn, trac, visualsvn-server

I have Trac set up on my VisualSVN server (using Subversion authentication), however every time I navigate to the Trac home page after opening the browser, I get the basic authentication dialog asking me for my username/password.  What I would like to do is have a login form in Trac, which would allow me to log in forever using cookies.

I have tried installing the AccountManagerPlugin, but I am completely unsure of how to correctly set it up.  (I am used to working with IIS on corporate intranets, so this is kind of alien to me)

I have managed to bypass the basic authentication dialog by setting this in my httpd-custom.conf:

```
AuthName "Trac"
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile "E:/Repositories/htpasswd"

#Require valid-user
```

I have tried using SvnServePasswordStore as my password store but I do not know which of the files in the repository directory to point it at.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: As far as i know VisualSVN has it's own Apache running which is in fact a second web-server. That mean there a two of them. If you like to authenticate only a single time you have to install trac on that server as well instead on IIS. So in my opinion this can't work.

Comment: Trac is installed on the Apache server.  I followed the instructions on the VisualSVN website to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have figured it out.

First, in httpd-custom.conf, I commented out the line:

```
Require valid-user
```

Then, I set the store for the AccountManagerPlugin to use the HtPasswdStore, which I pointed in Trac.ini at the htpasswd file in the repository root.

I am not sure if I can manage users within Trac, but I will be using VisualSVN to manage users so hopefully it shouldn't be an issue.